# Rmagick resize with just a width

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick, mogrify

Using mogrify, you can use the resize function just passing a width:

> Width given, height automagically selected to preserve aspect ratio.

I am trying to find the same option with Rmagick, but it seems that the resize method expects both width and height to be provided.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#change_geometry):

> Use the `change_geometry` method to resize an image with constraints such as "maintain the current proportions."

Try this, for example, where you want the new width to be 400px:

```
image = image.change_geometry("400") {|cols, rows, img| img.resize!(cols, rows)}
```